# Cancellation of a long call in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I am writing my WCF proxy by hand. Will the 4th function work, if I cancel the token? I'm mostly wondering if things will be ok when I call EndLongCall() before the WCF call has finished (asyncToken.IsComplete). I get the sense, not calling EndLongCall() is bad, but am not sure what happens if I call it early (when/if the ct is signaled).
I want to stop waiting on the client side (e.g. service has been signaled to shutdown). I'm avoiding using the TPL (Tasks).

```
public Pack[] LongCall()
{
    return Channel.LongCall();
}

public IAsyncResult BeginLongCall(AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
{
    return Channel.BeginLongCall(callback, asyncState);
}

public Pack[] EndLongCall(IAsyncResult result)
{
    return Channel.EndLongCall(result);
}

public Pack[] LongCall(CancellationToken ct)
{
    var asyncToken = BeginLongCall(null, null);
    WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] {ct.WaitHandle, asyncToken.AsyncWaitHandle});
    return EndLongCall(asyncToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling EndLongCall() early will result in blocking until the async operation completes. Which will **not** achieve the early cancellation.

> If the asynchronous operation represented by the IAsyncResult object
>   has not completed when EndOperationName is called, EndOperationName
>   blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is
>   complete.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm